# when to call _findclose?

Tags: c++, c

**Note: Since problem is solved, I've added comments to my original posts.**

According to "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkkkc1y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx", it stated as this:

*You must call _findclose after you are finished using either the _findfirst or _findnext function (or any variants). This frees up resources used by these functions in your application.*

**--comment:** it is vague, but what microsoft is trying to say is: some users just need to find the first file(they don't need to call _findnext), then call _findclose; some users called _findnext (they MUST have already called _findfirst), after finished using that, call _findclose. Actually _findnext can be called multiple times, while _findclose is only responsible to a handle, which is created by _findfirst.

And following is a piece of code that is widely used to list files in the directory. -- comment: it is correct.

For example, if there are 2 files and 1 directory in the directory, then:

```
.
..
ddd
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

_findfirst is called once.  the handle's corresponding fileinfo is system directory "." (is that right?)
**--comment:** no. the handle is a group of files+directories, the fileinfo is acting as the "cursor". (fileinfo always contained the "name" field, I bet the implementation of _findnext is using the "name" to find the next in a group of files+directories specified by the handle)

_findnext is called 4 times. (the first argument is always the handle corresponding to ".", is that right?)
**--comment:** yes + no. The first argument is always the same handle; the handle is NOT corresponding to any fileinfo, but to a group of them.

My questions are:

**Does "_findclose" be called ONCE is enough?**
**--comment:** yes.

**if _findnext will not change the handle value, how can it "remember" where to start to find the next file(or directory)? (sorry, maybe I was thinking in the "linked list" pattern.)**
**--comment:** I bet is using fileinfo's name field. Just as in Windows Explorer, we sort the contents in a folder, given a file name, we can know their position in the list, so we can "find next".

**Are there any harm to call _findclose more times than needed? (like crash or something)**
**--comment:** a stupid question. Sorry!

**Or is the following code wrong at all? If yes, what's the correct way to implement it?**
--It is correct code.

```
// List the files in the directory
intptr_t file;
_finddata_t filedata;
file = _findfirst(desc.c_str(),&filedata);
if (file != -1)
{
  do
  {
    cout << filedata.name << endl;
    // Or put the file name in a vector here
  } while (_findnext(file,&filedata) == 0);
}
else
{
  cout << "No described files found" << endl;
}
_findclose(file);
```

I asked this because I've met an issue that an application is freezing a directory which can not be deleted if the process is alive. However, I can guaranteed that  "_findclose" is called on every return value from "_findfirst". If I add "_findclose" after calling "_findnext", then will fix the issue perfectly. How can you help me to explain it?

**--comment:** pardon. don't use "guarantee" too easy. That's where the bug is.

Note: I don't have problem to understand what is a handle, like open a file, read/write/read/write..., close the file handle. I just find the documentations describing these three APIs are vague.

**--comment:** go to improve your english.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calls to _findclose should match with your calls to `_findfirst` -- i.e., each time you call `_findfirst`, you should have a matching call to `_findclose`.

In the code above, since you have only one call to `_findfirst`, it's correct to have only one call to `_findclose`.

If you were doing a recursive search of subdirectories, then you'd end up with multiple calls to `_findfirst` as you descend the hierarchy, and matching calls to `_findclose` as you finish and ascend back up the hierarchy.

Comment: does _findclose need to take care of _findnext? The statement at "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkkkc1y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx" confused me.

Comment: @milesma: no -- you call `_findfirst` once, then `_findnext` many times (depending on the number of files in the directory) then call `_findclose` once. It might be helpful to think of `_findfirst` as really being `_findopen`, making it more obvious that calls to `_findclose` should match with it.

Comment: Thanks. I pop up another question. When calling on _findfirst( aaa/bbb/*, ...), which folder is locked? My debugger shows the system directory "." is returned by fileinfo (the second parameter).

Comment: @milesma: That really has nothing to do with `_findfirst` and company. Any directory containing the .exe or any .dll used by a process will remain locked (can't be deleted) as long as the process is executing.

Comment: problem solved! Yes, you are correct! _findclose only need to take care of _findfirst. My bug was that a handle is not closed. This handle was a group of files inside a directory. When I'm trying to delete the top level directory, although these files can be deleted, the handle for them is not released, so caused the files' residing folder can not be deleted. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call _findclose once, when you are finished.

On Windows, a directory may be locked if it is the current directory of your process.  Try calling [_chdir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7fwze1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

If that doesn't work... are you opening any of the files in the directory you're searching?  An open file may lock the directory as well.

It may be useful to let [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) get a look at your app.  It can tell you for sure what handle you have left open.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on windows, I did switch directory by _chdir, but the problem still exists.